# Future<bool> vs bool in Flutter

Tags: if-statement, flutter, dart

I created an rest api method like below,

```
  Future<bool> activateAccount(int id, int code) async{
      final body = {"code": '$code'};

      final response = await client.post(
        '$baseUrl/user/account/$id',
        body: body
      );
      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        return true;
      }else return false;
  }
```

but i can't use this method in `if` statement like this:

```
bool a = userApiService.activateAccount(...)
if(a){
   ...
}
```

because:

```
A value of type 'Future<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
```

in what is problem? 
how to change this method to return it boolean depending on the result of the operation?

I would like to include in my `raisedButton` if statement:

```
 child: RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                userApiService.activateAccount(sharedPreferences.getInt('newUserId'), int.parse(activeCode));
                                // sharedPreferences.clear();
                              },
                              child: Text("ENTER",
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                              shape:
                                  RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0)),
                              color: Colors.red,
                            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning the bool like this shorter than yours;

```
Future<bool> activateAccount(int id, int code) async {
  final body = {"code": '$code'};

  final response = await client.post('$baseUrl/user/account/$id', body: body);
  return response.statusCode == 200;
}
```

And to use return value is you need to use `await` keyword;

```
bool a = await userApiService.activateAccount(...)
if(a){
   ...
}
```

for using with your button just add `async` keyword before curly brackets;

```
onPressed: () async {
  bool a = await userApiService.activateAccount(...)
  if(a){
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show how this ```bool a = ...``` can look in function? because I need ```async```

Comment: Yes you need async function because you use a Future. For more detail you should put your code, where you use this `if (a)` , here